# How to change the menu in Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-menu

I have two different menu layouts. I want to change the inflated menu on runtime when a button is clicked.

Initially the menu is set to `@menu/navigation`. I want it to change to `@menu/navigation2` when button is clicked.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="th.ac.sd.sdschoolas.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="158dp"
            android:layout_x="23dp"
            android:layout_y="46dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo"
            android:padding="20dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**menu/navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/homeicon"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/newsicon01"
        android:title="@string/title_news" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar_page_empty"
        android:title="@string/title_cal" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat_bubbles"
        android:title="@string/title_sms" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav5"
        android:icon="@mipmap/more"
        android:title="@string/title_more" />

</menu>
```

**menu/navigation2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/seticon"
        android:title="@string/title_setting" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/moreicom"
        android:title="@string/title_more2" />

</menu>
```

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The menu can be inflated by overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

You may use an internal state to choose which menu to inflate, e.g.

```
private int menuToChoose = R.menu.navigation;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(menuToChoose, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Then, in your `OnClickListener` you need to change the state and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, e.g.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    menuToChoose = R.menu.navigation2;

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Just a note, `setSupportActionBar(id_of_toolbar)` needs to be set in order for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code for set menu programmetically...

```
navigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.name_menu);
```

Comment: I tried but not work. It says "Cannot resolve method inflateMenu(?)"

Comment: please look in  developer console for bottomnavigationview it have inflate method might be you forgot something or doing some wrong pelase let it check...

Comment: it works for me. but you need to remove "app:menu="@menu/navigation"" from layout and set it programmetically

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Menu's add() api to dynamically add menus

`menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Option1").setShortcut('3', 'c');`

You can get menu object in API

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```