# Toolbar menu not inflating

Tags: android, menu, kotlin, toolbar

I am making a contexual action bar by modifying the toolbar on long click of recyclerView which contains edit and delete. It works okay if I select / deselect the views, however if I click on edit, the menu doesn't appear until I focus on one of the edit texts. When I edit any entry, it works again. the toolbar textView is being updated but menu is not inflating

//Activity Expense_list

```
class Expenses_list : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnLongClickListener{


lateinit var expenses_recycler : RecyclerView
var expense_list_items :MutableList<expense_input> = ArrayList()
var selection_list_items :MutableList<expense_input> = ArrayList()
var db = DataBaseHandler(this)
var categ:String = ""
var is_in_action_mode = false
var edit_mode = false
private var counter = 0
lateinit var toolbar: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expenses_list)

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    categ= intent.getStringExtra("cat")
    textView.text = categ.capitalize()

    loadData()

    expenses_recycler = findViewById(R.id.expense_list_item)
    expenses_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    expenses_recycler.adapter = 
    Expense_Adapter(expense_list_items,this,this@Expenses_list)

    }

fun addObject(i:Int) {
    selection_list_items.add(expense_list_items[i])
    counter=counter+1
    changeMenu()
    updateCounter(counter)
}

private fun updateCounter(counter:Int) {
    if(counter==0)
    {
        textToolbar.text = "0 item selected"
    }
    else
    {
        textToolbar.text = "" + counter + "item selected"
    }
}

private fun removeObject(adapterPosition: Int) {
    selection_list_items.remove(expense_list_items[adapterPosition])
    counter=counter-1
    changeMenu()
    updateCounter(counter)
}

fun loadData() {
    expense_list_items.clear()

    var data = db.readDataExpense(categ)

    for (i in 0..(data.size - 1))
    {
        expense_list_items.add(data[i])
    }
}

override fun onLongClick(p0: View?): Boolean {
    toolbar.menu.clear()
    textToolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    is_in_action_mode = true
    expenses_recycler.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    return true
}

fun changeMenu() {
    when (counter) {
        0 -> {
            Toast.makeText(this,"counter=0",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            toolbar.menu.clear()
        }
        1 -> {
            Toast.makeText(this,"counter=1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            toolbar.menu.clear()
            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_toolbar_edit)
        }
        else -> {
            toolbar.menu.clear()
            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_toolbar)
        }
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when(item?.itemId)
    {
        R.id.edit->{
            edit_mode=true
            expenses_recycler.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        R.id.delete->{
            db.deleteExpense(selection_list_items)
            loadData()
           clearActionMode()
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun clearActionMode() {
    is_in_action_mode=false
    edit_mode=false
    selection_list_items.clear()
    toolbar.menu.clear()
    textToolbar.visibility = View.GONE
    textToolbar.text = "0 item selected"
    expenses_recycler.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(is_in_action_mode==true)
    {
        clearActionMode()
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed()
}


    }
```

//Adapter

```
     class Expense_Adapter(items 
:List<expense_input>,ctx:Context,el:Expenses_list) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Expense_Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var expl = el


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(context,expl,LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.expense_list,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.bindTo(list[position])
    }

    var list = items
    var context = ctx

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }


    class ViewHolder(v:View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v)
    {
        var mex :Expenses_list? = null
        var context : Context?= null
        var exp :expense_input ?= null

        constructor(ctx: Context,ex: Expenses_list,v: View):this(v){
            mex = ex
            context = ctx
            bl.setOnLongClickListener(mex)
            cb?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked) {
                    mex!!.addObject(adapterPosition)
                }
                else {
                    mex!!.removeObject(adapterPosition)
                }
            }
}

        fun bindTo(l: expense_input)
        {
            exp = l
            name?.setText(l.item)
            //name?.text = l.item
            am.setText(l.amount.toString())
            //am.text = l.amount.toString()
            d.text = l.date


            if(mex?.is_in_action_mode==false) {
                cb.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            else {
                cb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                cb.isChecked = false
            }


            if(mex?.edit_mode==false)
            {
                if(vs.displayedChild == 1)
                {
                    Log.d("action","here")
                    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expnote)
                    vs.showPrevious()
                }
            }
            if(mex!!.edit_mode)
            {
                Log.d("action","Edit")
                vs.showNext()
                cb.visibility = View.GONE
                ename.setText(exp?.item)
                eam.setText(exp?.amount.toString())
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list)
            }

            im.setOnClickListener {
                val db = DataBaseHandler(context!!)
                if(vs.displayedChild==1)
                {
                    if(eam.text.toString().isNotEmpty() && ename.text.toString().isNotEmpty())
                    {
                        var ex = l
                        ex.amount = eam.text.toString().toFloat()
                        ex.item = ename.text.toString()
                        db.UpdateDataExpense(ex)
                        mex?.clearActionMode()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Item is invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    val detailIntent = Intent(context, Exp_note::class.java)
                    detailIntent.putExtra("Note",l.id)
                    context!!.startActivity(detailIntent)
                }
            }
        }

        val name = v.textItem
        val am = v.textAmount
        val d = v.textDate
        val im = v.openNote
        val cb = v.cb
        val bl = v.biglinear
        val vs = v.viewSwitcher
        val ename = v.editItem
        val eam = v.EditAmount

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the normal way of inflating the menu, like provided in this accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805455/4232337

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to inflate different menus in one Activity did you try to create one menu that contains all items and set them to invisible by default? You could then override onPrepareOptionsMenu, for example like below, to change what items are to be displayed based on your defined conditions:

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    invalidateOptionsMenu()
    when {
        // more than one item selected
        mSelectedItems.isNotEmpty() && mSelectedItems.size > 1 -> {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit).isVisible = false
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete).isVisible = true
        }
        // one item selected
        mSelectedItems.isNotEmpty() -> {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit).isVisible = true
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete).isVisible = true
        }
        // none selected
        else -> {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit).isVisible = false
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete).isVisible = false
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

[obove code produces following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjVl5.gif)

Comment: my mSelectedItems list is changing dynamically and I want to change menu accordingly

Comment: Do you need the menu to look and behave differently when the list changes? If not I see no easier way than than just displaying/hiding the menu items that are currently needed whenever a certain condition is met instead of inflating a whole other menu every time.

Comment: I added a GIF to my my answer, please tell me if the shown behavior is comparable to what you want to achieve, because I may have understood you incorrectly.

Comment: Yes this is what I want to achieve. Can you send me the complete code for this including the recyclerView. I tried making it without the checkbox but couldn't

Comment: I created a new github repo where I might upload my future training/experimental projects. https://github.com/ZeGerm4n/android-basics-kotlin the ToDoApp is what you have seen on the GIF. If this ultimately helps you somehow to solve your problem please mark this answer as accepted. Good Day